# Continuous partial derivatives and differentiability

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

A theorem says that continuous partial derivatives in an open set imply differentiability of a function. Here's a pair that's bugging me :
$$ f(r,\varphi) = r\sin^2 2\varphi \\
   g(r,\varphi) = r\sin 3\varphi   \\
   x = r \cos\varphi  \\
   y = r \sin\varphi $$
So the first one's partials by x and y intuitively by their 3D plot should be zero in $(0,0)$ (being reasonably flat around the x , y axis) and obviously defined and continuous everywhere else , the second one has whole lines through origin , but the two are not differentiable there. What am I missing here.

Comment: The partials $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ are _not_ continuous at the origin. "Vanishes at the origin and continuous everywhere else" does not imply continuous at the origin.

Comment: But don't the partials vanish also along both the axes , thus being constant and continuous ?

Comment: Yes, the partials vanish along the axes. Or in any case I'm willing to take your word for that. That does not imply the partials are continuous at the origin! Look at $\partial f/\partial x$ at $(t,t)$, for example.

Comment: Ah, okay, that clears it up , except $\partial f/\partial x (t,at)$ still amounts to zero for $a=1$.

Comment: Whatever, I didn't write down the details...